# will i7 support VMware ESX virtualisation?

Tags: vt-x

I want to but a DELL Studio 15 with core i7-740QM and install VMware ESX virtualisation into that.

Can anybody tell will it work or do i need to go with any other processor?

Thanx in advance.

Vinod

Comment: The processor is no problem but be sure to check the hardware compatibility list of esx 4. It comes with a quite limited set of hardware drivers. http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?action=search&deviceCategory=io&productId=1&keyBasic=cna&maxDisplayRows=50&key=&release[]=-1&datePosted=-1&vid=&did=&svid=&ssid=

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Intel - Virtualization Technology List](http://ark.intel.com/VTList.aspx) all of the i7 cores support Intel VT-x.

And versions of VMware ESX support Intel VT and AMD-V, but some older versions seem to have host/guest restrictions regarding 32 vs 64bits - If you're using ESX 4, you should be OK, otherwise there's a version list of what version support what on the [VMWare communities site](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-9150), have a look at that and see if the version you intend to run matches up with what guest/host systems you intend to run, given a 64bit processor.